# Screen dimensions not effective?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know and apply the form to get the dimensions of the screen, but something fails because apparently it is not effective in all the resolutions. If for example I define the location of some Buttons for a small resolution, those Buttons slides down as I run the application in higher resolutions. In the drawing below I have given the example of how the Buttons appear in an Emulator 2.7 QVGA API 25 (small) and in a Nexus 7 API 25 (xlarge). Have I to conclude that Android Studio has a failure?  Please, help me to see my problem since I have searched and set it out before but I haven’t received any correct answers.
This is my xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout1">

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is my java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

View pulsado;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Width and height of screen
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    // Buttons are placed
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // Size of Buttons
        rel_btn.width = 4 * width / 100;
        rel_btn.height = 4 * width / 100;
        // Position of Buttons
        switch (i) {
            case 1:  // top left
                rel_btn.leftMargin = 0;
                rel_btn.topMargin = 0;
                break;
            case 2: // top right
                rel_btn.leftMargin = 96 * width / 100;
                rel_btn.topMargin = 0;
                break;
            case 3:  // lower left
                rel_btn.leftMargin = 0;
                rel_btn.topMargin = 80 * height / 100;
                break;
            case 4:  // lower right
                rel_btn.leftMargin = 96 * width / 100;
                rel_btn.topMargin = 80 * height / 100;
                break;
        }
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
        btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        btnTag.setId(0 + i);
        btnTag.setOnClickListener(prueba);
        layout.addView(btnTag);
    }
}

    private View.OnClickListener prueba = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (pulsado != null) {
                Button button1 = (Button) pulsado;
                button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            Button button2 = (Button) view;
            GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
            drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
            drawable.setStroke(8, Color.RED);
            button2.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            pulsado = view;
        }
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the minSDKVersion of the project?

Comment: minSDKVersion 17

Comment: compileSdkVersion 28;     targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Bud, firstly, your app won't run on 2.7 inch real Android Device because there are none and Secondly, you can use Gridlayout if that is what you want to achieve. Since there are many Android devices of different screen Configuration it's hard to achieve same UI on every device.

Comment: OK, the app won’t run on 2.7 inch, but what about Galaxy Nexus API 25 where the Buttons also appear exactly at the four squares?

Comment: Post an image what you want to achieve.

Comment: The image is the first one, that is, that the four buttons appear in the correct place in all the resolutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173745/discussion-between-f-alvarado-and-aman-verma).

Comment: You checked my answer or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the button in layout file itself.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layout1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have seen and proved it, but the problem continues.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to Clean Project. I'll do some changes and I'll tell you.

Comment: There I have the problem: when clicking on each button I want this to beccome red. However, the two buttons below continue with the need to be clicked on the wrong position. I’m trying to see how to solve the problem.

Comment: I think I have resolved your issue. Please accept the answer. And if you still have a problem you can ask a new question since the dimension problem is resolved.